# Python eve: using Sub Resource value in $match

Tags: python, eve

I need to get a value inside an url (/some/url/value as a Sub Resource) usable as a parameter in an aggregation $match :

```
event/mac/11:22:33:44:55:66  --> {value:'11:22:33:44:55:66'}
```

and then:

```
{"$match":{"MAC":"$value"}},
```

here is a non-working example :

```
event = {
  'url': 'event/mac/<regex("([\w:]+)"):value>',
  'datasource': {
     'source':"event",
     'aggregation': {
        'pipeline': [
           {"$match": {"MAC":"$value"}},
           {"$group": {"_id":"$MAC", "total": {"$sum": "$count"}}},
        ]
     }
  }
}
```

this example is working correctly with :

```
event/mac/blablabla?aggregate={"$value":"aa:11:bb:22:cc:33"}
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: sorry, what exactly is the expected output here?

Comment: this question is related to Python eve's settings.py configuration file

Answer (score 0):

The real quick and easy way would be to

```py
path = "event/mac/11:22:33:44:55:66"
value = path.replace("event/mac/", "")
# or 
value = path.split("/")[-1]
```